# How to add underline for Hyperlinkbutton in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How to add underline for text of `HyperLinkButton` in windows phone 8.1:

XAML tag:

```
<HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource myHyperlink}" Content="Forgot Password?" />
```

By default control I don't find any underline for control nor find any text property by which text gets underline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use Underline property as follows

```
 <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="forgetpassword">
        <TextBlock>
            <Underline>
            <Run>Forgot Password?</Run>
                </Underline>
        </TextBlock>
    </HyperlinkButton>
```